# Study continuity of function

Tags: continuity

I'm trying to study continuity of a function, but I can't find a way to prove it.

> $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{1-\cos(x^2y)}{x^8+y^4}&\text{for } (x,y)\ne(0,0)\\ 0 &\text{for }(x,y) =(0,0) \end{cases}$$

I am thinking of finding $2$ expressions for $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ and to apply it to the function, but I'm pretty sure that it's not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the fact that when $X\to 0$,

$$1-\cos (X)=2\sin^2 (X/2)\sim \frac {X^2}{2} $$

we find that $$\lim_{x\to0}f (x,x^2)=\frac {1}{4}\ne f (0,0). $$

$f $ is not continuous at $(0,0) $.

Comment: The first approximation... where is it from?

Comment: @arcilli Don't you know that $\sin (X)\sim X $ or in other terms $\lim_0\frac {\sin (X)}{X}=1$

Comment: Showing that taking the limits, as (x, y)  goes to (0, 0) along two **different** paths, give two different answer is sufficient to show that the actual limit does not exist.  However, showing that the limits along two different paths ARE the same is not sufficient to show that the limit exists.

Comment: Sure, I know that fundamental limit and I understand how it's deducted the first relation. But, I dont figure it out how it's implemented in the second one